# Azure Logic App Recurrence Trigger - Is it possible to skip triggering on weekends?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Is it possible to skip triggering of Azure Logic Apps over weekends using Recurrence trigger ? or any other trigger

Thanks
Prabath

Comment: Thanks all. I already found the solution. The Recurrence trigger supports advanced options.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/concepts-schedule-automated-recurring-tasks-workflows#schedule-triggers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, you can specify which days to run：

[image]

Maybe like this：

[image]

You can refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-recurrence#add-recurrence-trigger).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. I already found the solution. The Recurrence trigger supports advanced options.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/concepts-schedule-automated-recurring-tasks-workflows#schedule-triggers[![enter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/concepts-schedule-automated-recurring-tasks-workflows#schedule-triggers%5B!%5Benter) image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzhyX.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzhyX.png)